# Drupal Site Download : Not able to install site as-is

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I recently downloaded a fully functional drupal(6) site using FTP. Though I installed the Drupal instance, I got the modules and the themes that were in the sites/all folder, but wasn't able to get the actual site configuration ( Configuration and Settings of those modules )

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have migrated the database also right? Right?!? :)

Comment: Yes I also migrated the database ( Should that be done after drupal is installed or before ? ) I did it after installing drupal because if I did it before installation, it asked me to empty the database or view the existing site ( which was not installed ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a follow-on of: [Drupal Site install on localhost after downloading source using FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807752/drupal-site-install-on-localhost-after-downloading-source-using-ftp/11809314#11809314)

If you get the Drupal install screen when accessing a site you've just migrated to your localhost, it's likely because you're trying to access the site locally using a URI that's different than the remote site AND this URL does not fall within the directories that Drupal searches when looking for a settings.php file (see comments starting about line 20 in the default.settings.php file of the sites/default folder).

**You have two options:**

**Option 1:** Create a symbolic link on your localhost that points requests to your local URI to the directory hosting the live site. This would look something like this:

```
ln -s /path/to/webroot/sites/default/ /path/to/webroot/sites/mydevsite.dev
```

**Option 2:** Create a sites/sites.php file that maps URI's to the correct folder hosting your settings.php file. For example, you'd add this to sites/sites.php if you left your settings.php file in the sites/default folder:

```
$sites['mysite.dev'] = 'default';
$sites['www.mysite.dev'] = 'default';
$sites['mysite.com'] = 'default';
$sites['www.mysite.com'] = 'default';
```

Simply put, this translates into: "Serve sites mysite.dev, www.mysite.dev, mysite.com, and www.mysite.com from the folder located at sites/default."

I usually use the second option. It's more sustainable, OS independent, and can be committed to source control.

---

**Update based first 5 comments:**

You need to edit the `.htaccess` file in your Drupal install. Look for this section:

```
  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /
```

And do as it says, uncomment out the line and set it to your subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you @roberthernandez for the reply but still in small fix :) 

The name of my local folder is **abhi** which is the site that I will be working on ( localhost/abhi is my URL ).

I used the second option as suggested and created a sites/sites.php.



`<?php

$sites['rtd'] = 'default';
$sites['www.rtd.dk'] = 'default';
$sites['rtd'] = 'default';
$sites['www.rtd'] = 'default';

?>`

But the issue is that, I am just able to load the first page and not all the other modules related to the site. 

For example, localhost/abhi/admin or localhost/abhi/build/modules, return a white screen of death

Comment: No, Not as of now. I still am trying to figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: You need to enable mod_rewrite on your localhost.

Comment: It still is the same even after enabling mod_rewrite from the Terminal using `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: I successfully managed to get the first page of my live site into the localhost running, but the pages that are created, taxonomy, the views, og and the other configuration stuff is completely missing ( including the css and the navigation bar on the first page ). I have all my files in `/sites/default/files/` and the `sites/sites.php` also exists.

Comment: The proper steps for migration are: 1) Put live site in maintenance mode; 2) Backup live site and database; 3) Restore database locally; 4) Restore files locally; 5) Check/update your settings.php file, file/folder permissions, and sites.php mappings. If it doesn't work after that, you're going to need more direct help as it's not Drupal related, it's likely a difference in your web server configuration. Add a bounty.

Comment: For Step 2 I used backup & migrate module and created a restore which had an SQL file. For Step 3 used the same file. For Step 4 I copied all the files that I downloaded using the FTP onto my localhost folder ( /var/www/abhi ). Step 5, I chmodded 777 for all the files and folders in the `abhi` folder. Are these steps correct ?

Comment: No.. I've been trying various methods and none of them work. Repeated all the steps again and again after doing a fresh install of Drupal altogether. 

Mine is just a White Screen of Death page .. Please tell me the required shots and I will host them online ..

Answer (score 0):

Yes the steps are correct. Is it the design that is not coming or is the functionality of views missing? If its only the css that is not coming, then the issue could be that your theme is not getting applied. Check if the theme folder correctly exists, and disable/enable the theme.

Comment: The Functionality of the views and the theme. Both of them are missing. The modules and the theme folder exist and the permissions are also totally all right.